# Half of half cycle of sine wave

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

How can I identify the increasing and decreasing side of half cycle of sine wave using MATLAB code (.m file). For example the flag should set 1 if the amplitude of sine wave is increasing from 0 deg to 90 deg and should set 0 when amplitude is decreasing from 90 deg to 180 deg.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set the `incFlag` to 1 (true actaully) when the values for `y` are increasing and `y` is positive
which I inferred from your 0-90 comment.  If you want all increasing values then un-comment the line below.

[image: Output Flag]

```
x = 0:.1:5*pi;
y = sin(x);

dY = [diff(y) 0]; %Add one element to array
incFlag = dY > 0 & y > 0;  
% incFlag = dY > 0;  

a(1) = subplot(2,1,1);plot(x,y);grid on
a(2) = subplot(2,1,2);plot(x,incFlag);grid on
linkaxes(a,'x')
```